# BSD Mail - Single Sending Address

Tags: email, mail-command

I've been working on sending HTML emails using BSD mail and so far I've been successful. I've even been able to modify, not change though, the sender.

Current Command:

```
cat $htmlFile | mail -s "$(echo -e "$subject\nContent-Type: text/html")" $recipient -v -- -F $sender
```

However when the email comes through, the sender is only appending the $sender to the host name. Let's assume that the following is true

```
$user=root
$HOSTNAME=server.com
$sender='Application Support<support@acmeinc.com>'
```

When the email comes through it reads:

```
Application Support<support@acmeinc.com> <root@server.com>
```

How can I make it so that only the $sender variable is used in the email instead of appended?

OS: RHEL 5.10 
Kernel Rev: 2.6.18-371.8.1.el5

Note: I've posted this same question on stackoverlfow with no response: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26025218/bash-mail-send-as-another-user-only